# Aurelia Custom Elements & Content

Tags: aurelia

I was reading through [this tutorial](http://blog.durandal.io/2015/04/24/aurelia-custom-elements-and-content-selectors/) and I want to do something similar, but instead of using attributes of my custom elements, I'll like to access the content inside of my custom element tags. I can't seem to figure this out. So instead of html looking like this:

```
<modal>  
  <modal-header title="Edit Person"></modal-header>
  <modal-body content="person-information"></modal-body>
  <modal-footer buttons.bind="['Cancel']"></modal-footer>
</modal>
```

I want it to look more like this:

```
<modal>  
  <modal-header>Edit Person</modal-header>
  <modal-body>
      <form>...</form>
  </modal-body>
  <modal-footer buttons.bind="['Cancel']"></modal-footer>
</modal>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that can be accomplished with Content Selectors -

modal-header.html

```
<template>
  <slot></slot>
</template>
```

You can be more specific as well by specifying what content to match using any standard CSS selector -

```
<template>
  <slot="form"></slot>
  <slot select=".form-element"></slot>
</template>
```

[Aurelia documentation](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-content-projection)

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but `<custom-element>Here's my content</custom-element>` and `<template><div class="my-custom-element"><content></content></div></template>` ends up with an empty div for me :/

Comment: Note that the `<content>` tag has been replaced by the `<slot>` tag in the version 1 of Aurelia, in accordance with the latest changes to the Shadow DOM specification.  [Aurelia documenation](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-content-projection)

Comment: Definitely edit welcome else I'll try to get to this